# DateTime WHERE Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities, where-clause

I have a gridview that is populated from an entitydatasource in asp.net. In my c# code-behind I need to add a WHERE parameter to the entity data source that will filter out all data that is not >= validDate1 and <= validDate2.

Here is where I'm at:

```
using (RamRideOpsEntities myEntities = new RamRideOpsEntities())
{
    var validDates = (from a in myEntities.AdminOptions
                      select new { a.ValidDate1, a.ValidDate2 }).FirstOrDefault();

    if (validDates != null)
    {
         RidesGridView.Where = "  ..... ??? " //TODO
    }
}
```

Edit: with the answers below, let me be more clear.. the validDates = .... statement is just getting the two valid dates I need to filter by.. there 'where' clause needs to be added to the entity data source so the data displayed in the grid view is within the valid date range.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to filter at the database...

Comment: I could be wrong, but it was my understanding that when using an entity data source, the where clause would be applied before data was actually retrieved from the db, so in effect that is what I am trying to do.

Comment: @SHeinema - No, just try the code we posted.  It will work.

Comment: The validDates object will never be null, so there's no need for the null check.

Comment: @SHeinema - are you using asp.net or winforms?  They're different GridView controls.  Neither has a Where property though, so I don't know where you're getting that.

Comment: I'm using asp.net, sorry I was in a bit of a hurry earlier, indeed the where is added to the entity data source not the gridview, I guess my issue is that I was trying to add the where clause from c# in a way like David B. suggested below. I was trying to avoid what others were suggesting below (filtering the data by date in the LINQ way) because I would then have to change more of my other code to bind the gridview to the datasource in c# rather than in the entitydatasource declaration in the aspx page as is currently the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using an EntityDataSource.  This is a very un-linq type which allows you to use runtime-defined strings to modify queries.  A more linq-ish technique would prefer that the string is part of the language of the program, and the compiler would turn it into an expression tree (as others have posted).  That linq-ish approach won't work as long as you're using an EntityDataSource.

From the msdn article referencing [EntityDataSource.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.entitydatasource.where.aspx), it looks like you need to use the magic word "it" to describe the row.  Then you'd supply the parameters to the `.WhereParameters` collection.

Code:

```
using (myEntities = new RamRideOpsEntities())
{
      var validDates = (from a in myEntities.AdminOptions
                        select new { a.ValidDate1, a.ValidDate2 }).FirstOrDefault();

      if (validDates != null)
      {
         RidesEDS.Where = @"it.TimeOfCall >= @ValidDate1 AND it.TimeOfCall <= @ValidDate2";
         RidesEDS.WhereParameters.Add(@"ValidDate1", DbType.DateTime, validDates.ValidDate1.ToString());
         RidesEDS.WhereParameters.Add(@"ValidDate2", DbType.DateTime, validDates.ValidDate2.ToString());
      }
 }
```

Comment: Alright Mr David B, I'd say the green check-mark has to go to you. This is what I was trying to get at.. Pretty good guess at the code too, I added an edit with what ended up working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var validDates = (from a in myEntities.AdminOptions where 
    a.ValidDate1 >= validDate1 && a.ValidDate2 <= validDate2
    select new { a.ValidDate1, a.ValidDate2 }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't filter the GridView, you filter the data source.  The answer will depend on what kind of data source you have, but assuming it's Linq-compatible:

```
var items = dataSource.Where(
        d => d.Date >= validDates.ValidDate1 && d.Date <= validDates.ValidDate2
    );
RidesGridView.DataSource = items;
```